# How to create 2 menus inside one component view

Tags: custom-component, menu-item

I've create a component called `testComponent` with a specific view called `collection` which needs to have 2 layouts the `default.php` and the `list.php`.

I need to make both default and list as menu items and i don't want to use absolute path like `index.php?options=com_testComponent&view=collection&layout=list` as the item input.

I already added default as a menu item, but I don't know how i should add lists beside it. I used `default.xml` for it should i create `list.xml` or i have to write something inside default for the sake of having both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding list.xml i did added new menu item for list layout

Comment: If this is a solution to your issue, this is a poor way of sharing your discovery.  Your answer has been flagged by the system as Low Quality -- and rightly so.   I can't think of any case when a single sentence is a good, educational answer.  This site is not only about solving problems, but educating researchers so that they are empowered and grow as Joomla users/developers.  If this actually is a solution -- and I really can't tell if it is -- please edit your answer to improve the quality. Your question, too, could be improved with a screenshot of the current output and the desired output.

Comment: @mickmackusa Actually i just guessed as i typed the question as you could see. i don't have any clue how this works an why joomla searches for the files like this and when does it do that? obviously i couldn't find anything on Joomla doc that made me come here. so IDK what should I write here as source or just populate the answer with some jargon to avoid system flag...

Comment: That's okay.  If you don't know why/how it works, you may leave it unedited.   Perhaps someone else will come through and post a more thorough answer.